# TortoiseHG 'file not found' when pulling/pushing/cloning

Tags: windows-7, mercurial, push, tortoisehg, pull

I've installed `TortoiseHG 64bit` on my `Windows 7` laptop and worked with it with the last few weeks with no problems.

But today I tried to check for new incoming changes and the workbench returns me an error `Incoming from ssh://hg-project@mercurial.local.domain.nl:2224/project aborted, ret 255` and not showing the SSH password prompt.

The log message:

```
project% % hg --repository C:\Development\project incoming --quiet --bundle c:\users\admin\appdata\local\temp\thg.moqvtf\ssh__hg-project@mercurial.local.domain.nl2224_project_f4j7ry.hg ssh://hg-project@mercurial.local.domain.nl:2224/project
abort: Het systeem kan het opgegeven bestand niet vinden <-- Dutch for 'Can't find the file'
[command returned code 255 Sat Mar 02 13:35:22 2013]
project%
```

I looked in the directory `c:\users\admin\appdata\local\temp\thg.moqvtf\` and there are no files. I don't know what the `bundle` parameter does, maybe that it creates the file or something..

So I tried to clone the repo again, but same error, same goes for pushing. Also tried reinstalling TortoiseHG, but the same errors are returned.

Does anyone explain to me how this happend and how to fix it? Plus some info about the `bundle` parameter would be nice.

### update

I think it has something to do with SSH, because all the remote commands fail with the file not found error (i.e.`hg pull`). I already added the extra `ssh` property to the config file, but still no success :( :

```
[ui]
ssh="C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\TortoisePlink.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ssh="C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\TortoisePlink.exe" -ssh -2 -C -i (path_to_your_private_key)
```

or

```
ssh="C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\TortoisePlink.exe" -ssh -2 -C -batch
```

if you are using Pageant.

Comment: I don't have an private key, I always enter the password in the prompt that shows up..

Comment: can you try running the same command from the command line with `--verbose` added to the arguments?

Comment: I runned the command `hg pull --verbose` in the directory of the project and this is the output: `C:\Development\project>hg pull --verbose
running "TortoisePlink.exe" -ssh -2 hg-project@mercurial.local.domain.nl -P 2224
 "hg -R project serve --stdio"
abort: Het systeem kan het opgegeven bestand niet vinden`

Comment: is `mercurial.local.domain.nl` your own Windows 7 machine or is it a remote machine with sshd running on it?

Comment: No it's the server from my work (remote). I changed the domain name to `domain` for the public eye ;)

Comment: is it possible then that something has changed on the remote server? Add `-v` to the arguments for `ssh` and see if any messages from the server help.

Comment: No nothing changed there. Plus why then the error of the missing file? :S It's very enoying that the error message lacks any information about the file..

Comment: Does adding `-v` to the arguments of `ssh` give you any more information that might help?

Comment: Sorry didn't saw the update. Adding the -v to the ssh didn't gave any more info. You did mean to put the `-v` after the `ssh` line in the config right?